# Accelerate float rather than decelerate with Mathf.SmoothDamp - Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Mathf.SmoothDamp to slow down my float speed and I succeeded! But I do not know how to speed up the value of this float, I now only want to accelerate slowly in the beginning and go to the maximum speed limit, as a real-life acceleration effect, cars and other! Does anyone have any ideas?

Code used by Mathf.SmoothDamp:

```
float speed, velocity;

void Update(){
      //Used successfully to slow down
      speed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(speed , 20f, ref velocity, 5f);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at one of [Robert Penner's easing function](https://easings.net/en) and pick the one that fits your needs. Then, you will easily find [C# implementations](https://gist.github.com/mrhelmut/3b70813cacc6c2e1e9f853b74e124dae) of those functions.

Comment: I chose the easeInQuart I do not know which values to use in this function now!
public static float In(float t, float b, float c, float d)
        {
            return c * (t /= d) * t * t * t + b;
        }

Comment: Please include the code showing how you are using `Mathf.SmoothStep` to calculate position/velocity.

Comment: @Ruzihm I tried to use the smoothstep, it has the acceleration effect as it slows down at the end of the curve until it reaches the maximum limit, I want to accelerate at the beginning gently until it reaches the end for example 20f but without accelerating slowly like smoothstep!

Comment: @FulanotalGames It's hard for us to know what variables you are working with if you include none of your own code. It's easier for you to just show what you already have than for us to try and guess what variables you are working with and write an answer that might not even help.

Comment: @Ruzihm I added code in the question, so this code is to slow down, and it works, I want to speed up.

Comment: @Hellium Thanks, I searched more about these links yours and I got from them to solve, if you want to put as an answer I mark it! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make an ease in quart function and an inverse, clamping inputs between 0 and 1 (which also clamps the outputs):

```
public float EaseInQuart(float t) {
    return Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Clamp01(t),4f);
}

public float InverseEaseInQuart(float x) {
    return Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Clamp01(x),0.25f);
}
```

Now we can take the current speed, divide it by the max speed to get our `x` term.

Convert that using our `InverseEaseInQuart` method to get our linear t term, which we can change by `deltaTime` scaled by some `acceleration` value.

Then we use convert back to x using `EaseInQuart` and then multiply that by max speed again to get our new current speed.

Altogether this could be written as:

```
public float maxSpeed = 25f;
public float speed = 0f;
public float acceleration = 0.1f; // (0 to maxSpeed in 10 seconds)

public float EaseInQuart(float t) {
    return Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Clamp01(t),4f);
}

public float InverseEaseInQuart(float x) {
    return Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Clamp01(x),0.25f);
}

void Update(){ 
    float x = speed / maxSpeed;

    float t = InverseEaseInQuart(x);

    t += Time.deltaTime * acceleration;

    x = EaseInQuart(t);

    speed = x * maxSpeed;
}
```

Comment: Using the function that the Hellium link worked for me, yours tested and also worked, I will use his to use less code. hehe

Comment: @FulanotalGames Fair enough :)